# Problems using meteors upsert

Tags: meteor, upsert

using METEOR@1.1.0.2 and doing an `upsert` on the server side gives me problems. It either complains that the syntax is wrong for insert or update, or am I just doing it wrong?

The code below will work on inserts but on updates throw:

> Error: Update parameter cannot have both modifier and non-modifier fields.

```
Mail.upsert({ ma_user_id: userId }, {
  ma_user_id: userId,
  ma_address: userEmail,
  ma_verified: false
}, function (e, r) {
  console.log(e, r);
});
```

The code below works on updates but will throw this error on inserts:
MongoError:

> The dollar ($) prefixed field '$exists' in 'removed.$exists' is not valid for storage.

```
Mail.upsert({ ma_user_id: userId }, { $set: {
    ma_user_id: userId,
    ma_address: userEmail,
    ma_verified: false
  }
}, function (e, r) {
  console.log(e, r);
});
```

I have also tried this which gives me the error on update:

> Error: Update parameter cannot have both modifier and non-modifier fields.

```
Mail.update({ ma_user_id: userId }, {
    ma_user_id: userId,
    ma_address: userEmail,
    ma_verified: false
  }, {
    upsert: true
  }, function (e, r) {
    console.log(e, r);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message basically says that you cannot use the same field in both selector and modifier. So you have to remove `ma_user_id` from the modifier like this:

```
Mail.upsert({ ma_user_id: userId }, {      
  ma_address: userEmail,
  ma_verified: false
}, function (e, r) {
  console.log(e, r);
});
```

Comment: Doing this will not add the `ma_user_id` field if an insert happens.